# MvvmCross and intersoft crosslight combination

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have recently started building xamarin.ios native app using MvvmCross framework but I found intersoft crosslight UI components are more robust and easy to implement. Can anybody suggest me whether I have to stick with MvvmCross or switch into intersoft crosslight or combined both?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MvvmCross does not prevent you from using any custom UI components. If you need TwoWay bindings for a specific View, you will need to provide a custom Target Binding class for that. Otherwise all public properties are able to be bound OneWay out of the box.

We have documentation on creating your own Target Binding in the [official MvvmCross documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/custom-data-binding).

One thing you might want to consider is to not use a library that hasn't been updated for over 800 days. I have no experience with Crosslight, but no updates for that long raises some alarms and signals that the product is dead.

Comment: Thank you @Cheesebaron for your suggestion. I will keep in mind about update of intersoft crosslight.